# firebase remote config. fetching failure: http code 403 unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-api, firebase-remote-config

I started getting 403 errors when initializing remote config in my application.
Everything was working fine until a while ago. I connected google play services and set up oauth for them and from about that time, remote config stopped working. The google play games authorization is working fine. I have no idea what or where I need to check to get remote config working again. This has been going on for a week now. I haven't found any questions like this on the internet, it's like no one has dealt with this.

Error:
[image]

Code section where an error occurs (everything works correctly up to line 47):
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fixed in Remote Config v21.1.1 and Firebase BOM v30.3.0. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If your building a mobile game, then I would recommend using ByteBrew for your remote configs. They deliver configs sub-second (I think my average configs deliver in ~100ms). They also have a dashboard to add and edit configs, as well the ability to create revolving configs based on time intervals, and they are free.